# Including single aar modules of a library project through jitpack / Github

Tags: android, git, android-gradle-plugin, aar, jitpack

I`m maintaining an android project with just an android library module in it. This is accessed by other projects through an upload from Git to jitpack and then referencing it as dependency in gradle.

```
implementation "com.github.<profilename>:<libprojectname>:1.0.0"
```

Is it possible to have further android library modules, which are independent from each other, and include them separatly in the gradle script of the other projects?